# php unable to delete Images

Tags: php, filesystems, delete-file

I have below code to delete posts from my website. This function is working for video posts and it delete video post perfectly. But it is not working for image posts and does not delete post image from web directory. My code is

```
function delete_post($id, $fromStory = false) {
    $post = get_post($id);
    if ($fromStory and !$post['is_story']) return true;
    if (!$fromStory and !can_edit_post($post)) return false;
    if ($post['images']) {
        $images = perfectUnserialize($post['images']);
        if($images) {
            foreach($images as $image) {
                delete_file(path($image));
            }
        }

        if ($post['video']) {
            delete_file(path($post['video']));
        }
}
```

Besides i have delete old stories function given below

```
function delete_old_stories() {
    $time = time() - (3600 * config('story-deleted-at', 24));
    $query = db()->query("SELECT id,post_id FROM story_posts WHERE time_created < $time ");
    while($fetch = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        db()->query("DELETE FROM story_posts WHERE id=?", $fetch['id']); //delete story posts
        delete_post($fetch['post_id'], true);
    }
    return true;
}
```

This is delete file function

```
function delete_file($path)
{
    $basePath = path();
    $basePath2 = $basePath . '/';

    if ($path == $basePath or $path == $basePath2) return false;
    if (is_dir($path) === true) {
        $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path), RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);

        foreach ($files as $file) {
            if (in_array($file->getBasename(), array('.', '..')) !== true) {
                if ($file->isDir() === true) {
                    rmdir($file->getPathName());
                } else if (($file->isFile() === true) || ($file->isLink() === true)) {
                    unlink($file->getPathname());
                }
            }
        }

        return rmdir($path);
    } else if ((is_file($path) === true) || (is_link($path) === true)) {
        return unlink($path);


    }

    return false;
}
```

For each story, Image file in directory is

```
_1000_8f81946314be5cfe962480b96c7df11e.jpg
```

For Post, Image files in directory are

```
_1000_8f81946314be5cfe962480b96c7df11e.jpg
_600_8f81946314be5cfe962480b96c7df11e.jpg
```

Delete Story is working fine and it delete story images but delete post does not delete images.

Comment: Have you check the permissions on the posts folder ?

Comment: Folder permission is 755, i also tried with 777. Besides story images got deleted from the same folder so there should not be any issue with folder permission.